# Interpolation of 3D coordinate

Tags: interpolation

> How to determine the value of x and y between two point of 3D coordinate (x,y,z)?
>   I have known the value of z = -162.4
>   and here is my data points:

```
{40.7819, -56.2653, -162.34}, {41.8232, -55.4957, -163.152}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a question about Mathematica.. did you try to write down the equation for that line, solve it for z=-162.4 and get the corresponding point?

Comment: I am looking for the formulation of 3D interpolation, but I did not find. I know maybe it's not a question about Mathematica. But, is it possible solve by mathematica?

Comment: If the math is clear to you I don't think it should be a problem to do this. Anyway, here is a Mathematica equivalent of my comment: `line[t_] := (1 - t) {40.7819, -56.2653, -162.34} + t {41.8232, -55.4957, -163.152}; line[t] /. Solve[line[t][[3]] == -162.4, t][[1]]`